# Relationships between Grails domain classes with inheritance

Tags: grails, inheritance, grails-orm

I have the following class. In `src/groovy`,

```
class Profile {
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    byte[] photo
    String bio
}
```

The domain classes `BasicProfile` and `AcademicProfile` extend `Profile`.

```
class BasicProfile extends Profile {

    User user
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false
        middleName nullable: true
        lastName blank: false
        photo nullable: true, maxSize: 2 * 1024**2
        bio nullable: true, maxSize: 500
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerSubclass true
    }
}

class AcademicProfile extends Profile {

    User user
    String dblpId
    String scholarId
    String website
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasMany = [publications: Publication]

    static constraints = {
        importFrom BasicProfile
        dblpId nullable: true
        scholarId nullable: true
        website nullable: true, url: true
        publications nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = { 
        tablePerSubclass true
    }
}
```

Then there is a `Publication` class.

```
class Publication {

    String dblpId
    String scholarId
    String title
    String description
    Date publicationDate
    int citations
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static belongsTo = [AcademicProfile]
    static hasOne = [publisher: Publisher]
    static hasMany = [academicProfiles: AcademicProfile]

    static constraints = {
        dblpId nullable: true
        scholarId nullable: true
        title blank: false, maxSize: 100
        description nullable: true, maxSize: 500
        publicationDate: nullable: true
        academicProfiles nullable: false
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a `User` class.

```
class User {

    String username
    String password
    String email
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasOne = [basicProfile: BasicProfile, academicProfile: AcademicProfile]

    static constraints = {
        username size: 3..20, unique: true, nullable: false, validator: { _username ->
            _username.toLowerCase() == _username
        }
        password size: 6..100, nullable: false, validator: { _password, user ->
            _password != user.username
        }
        email email: true, blank: false
        basicProfile nullable: true
        academicProfile nullable: true
    }
}
```

My questions are as follows.

1. I want a relationship where each `User` may optionally have a `Profile` (either `BasicProfile` or `AcademicProfile`). I tried `static hasOne = [profile: Profile]` but I got errors saying `Profile` does not agree to the `hasOne` relationship. So the current setup I have is a workaround. Is there no way a user can have one `Profile` be it `BasicProfile` or `AcademicProfile`?
2. Secondly, in the current setup, I get the error: `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table academic_profile_publications refers to an unmapped class: org.academic.AcademicProfile` when I try to run it. A Google search tells me that this is a problem with classes which are inheriting from other classes. So technically, if I don't have a `hasMany` relationship in `Publication` with `AcademicProfile`, it should work without any issues. But I don't want that. Because a *publication* has many *authors* (`AcademicProfile`s in my case) and an *author* may have many publications. So is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using Hibernate inheritance - that requires that all of the classes be mapped. You're just using regular Java/Groovy inheritance where you inherit properties and methods from base classes. But Hibernate isn't aware of that, so it can't do queries on the unmapped base class.

I'm not sure why it's complaining about `AcademicProfile`, but it could be a secondary bug caused by the core issue.

I find Hibernate inheritance to be way too frustrating to use in most cases, so I use this approach when there is shared code.

It should work if you move `Profile` to `grails-app/domain`. Once you do that you should move the `tablePerSubclass` mapping config to the base class and only specify it once.

Comment: I followed your advise and it worked. Now I am trying to have a one to one relationship b/w `User` and `BasicProfile` where `User` is the owner and another one to one relationship b/w `AcademicProfile` and `User` where `AcademicProfile` is the owner. I removed `academicProfile` from `hasOne` in and added it as a field in `User`. I added the `hasOne` to `AcademicProfile`. But it's failing with the error: `- Field error in object 'org.academic.User' on field 'academicProfile': rejected value [null];`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You should ask that in a separate question

Comment: here is the query as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512671/