# How to have multiple One-to-One relationships between three domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

As a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498631/), I want to have a `User` domain class which has an optional one-to-one relationship with `BasicProfile` domain class, `User` being the owner which may or may not have a profile. I have this part figured out. What I also want is an optional one-to-one relationship between the `AcademicProfile` domain class and the `User`, `AcademicProfile` being the owner, such that an `AcademicProfile` may or may not have a `User`. When I try to replicate this the way I did the first one-to-one relationship, it does not work. Here are my classes.

```
class User {

    String username
    String password
    String email
    AcademicProfile academicProfile
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasOne = [basicProfile: BasicProfile]

    static constraints = {
        username size: 3..20, unique: true, nullable: false, validator: { _username ->
            _username.toLowerCase() == _username
        }
        password size: 6..100, nullable: false, validator: { _password, user ->
            _password != user.username
        }
        email email: true, blank: false
        basicProfile nullable: true
    }
}

class BasicProfile extends Profile {

    User user
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

}

class AcademicProfile extends Profile {

    String dblpId
    String scholarId
    String website
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    static hasOne = [user: User]
    static hasMany = [publications: Publication]

    static constraints = {
        dblpId nullable: true
        scholarId nullable: true
        website nullable: true, url: true
        publications nullable: true
        user nullable: true
    }
}

class Profile {
    String firstName
    String middleName
    String lastName
    byte[] photo
    String bio

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false
        middleName nullable: true
        lastName blank: false
        photo nullable: true, maxSize: 2 * 1024**2
        bio nullable: true, maxSize: 500
    }

    static mapping = {
        tablePerSubclass true
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the error: `Field error in object 'org.academic.User' on field 'academicProfile': rejected value [null];`. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add `nullable:true` constraint for `AcademicProfile academicProfile` in User class as you mentioned that you need an 'optional' relationship between AcademicProfile & User.

The error itself is self explanatory though, that you can't create a User class's instance, without providing the academicProfile property a non-null value.

Comment: I've already tried that. And I get the error: `Message: Hibernate operation: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; NULL not allowed for column "ACADEMIC_PROFILE_ID"; SQL statement:
insert into user (id, version, academic_profile_id, date_created, email, last_updated, password, username) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-176]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "ACADEMIC_PROFILE_ID"; SQL statement:`

Comment: have a look at your DB structure, obviously the "ACADEMIC_PROFILE_ID" column has still NOT NULL constraint

Comment: @ArunAllamsetty : Could you share your updated Domain classes with constraints & the generated db structure for the same?